# Write 8-bit message

Tags: android, bluetooth, byte

I have to send a byte via bluetooth, the problem is that I can not use this script because I have to write the number that is greater than 127:

```
mChatService.write(new byte[]{});
```

how can I do?
Thanks.

EDIT

Logcat:

```
07-25 14:18:20.410: D/AndroidRuntime(1906): Shutting down VM
07-25 14:18:20.410: W/dalvikvm(1906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41607ce0)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): Process: com.example.android.BluetoothChat, PID: 1906
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$2.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:517)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
07-25 14:18:20.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Receive Code

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
// construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bytes in Java are signed so the max range is -128 to +127. If you really just need 1 byte, you can convert it to an integer on the receiving side and add 128 to it to make it in the range of 0-255.

Comment: The poster doesn't necessarily have the ability to modify the receiving side.

Comment: Good point Chris, but the receiving side shouldn't be expecting a number larger than 127 if it is only reading a single byte.

Comment: The receiving side doesn't necessarily consider the data to be signed bytes.  Most communication protocols don't consider arbitrary individual bytes to be signed, as they often group them into large values which may be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: @vmagro I can not change the receiver, how can I do otherwise?

Comment: As Chris said, the receiver may not consider the byte to be signed. Are you sure the receiver is only reading a single byte and not a 4 byte integer?